# TypeError: getItem is not a function when testing a component with node module hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs

I am learning React, and got stuck in testing one of my components.
I use react-use-cart to manage the cart, this is how code looks

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useCart } from "react-use-cart";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import handleQuantityChange from "../../logic/product/handleQuantityChange";

function AddToCart(props) {
    const {product, styles, loading} = props;
    const { addItem, inCart, getItem, updateItemQuantity } = useCart();
    const productInCart = getItem(product.id);
```

The test breaks at "productInCart = getItem(product.id)" saying " TypeError: getItem is not a function".
I've been stuck at this for several days, and would really appreciate some help, it's my first time asking a question, so if you need any more info let me know, thank you.

Also about the test, test breaks on the render stage

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import AddToCart from "../AddToCart";
import { MemoryRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
describe("get item is not a function", () => { 
    const product = {
        name: "test name",
        imgUrl: "test image",
        price: 555,
        shipping: 1000,
        id: 55
    }; 
    const styles = []


    beforeEach(() => {
        render(
            <Router>
                <AddToCart product={product} styles={styles}/>
            </Router>
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `CartProvider`:

```js
{...}

    beforeEach(() => {
        render(
          <CartProvider>
            <Router>
                <AddToCart product={product} styles={styles}/>
            </Router>
          </CartProvider>
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try logging the value of `getItem` to see if it's indeed a function ? Though I'm not familiar with use-cart it does seem like you're doing it correctly.
Other than that, the `addToCart` function is missing an ending curly brace, I assume you just didn't paste the whole code in ?

Comment: Yes, I did not paste the whole code, the cart provider suggested by Toni fixed the issue, thank you for responding :)